# Router not found in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I'm studying NodeJs and localhost it's all OK, however, when I deploy in azure I get this error:

```
Error: Not Found
    at app.use.res.render.message (D:\home\site\wwwroot\app.js:43:13)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:318:9)
    at SessionStrategy.authenticate (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\passport\lib\strategies\session.js:71:10)
    at attempt (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:341:16)
    at authenticate (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:342:7)
```

Below follows my code:
https://gist.github.com/StephanyBatista/3a2bfdd9aa3f9b7d170f

My doubt is why this code is ok in localhost and isn't ok in azure?

Comment: I've seen that when I deleted the "express-load" and have put in app.js, this it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, uhm, you're using:

`app.use(function(err, req, res, next)`

and the [definition](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) is:

`app.use(function(req, res, next)`

So next is null, because err = req, req = res, res = next, and next is null (you've shifted the parameters).

Just like you've used it in the previous function. More information on [middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html) explaining why it works this way.

Comment: I did your suggest, deleted the middleware, and still has error "not found".

Comment: If you have deleted something, then the error is on some other line of code. As far as I can see, you've used `app.use(function(err, req, res, next)` two times, so you need to remove them, and if still any errors - update the code you've posted.